# Can we delete default data directory(& data in it) of mysql in ubantu after moving the data into a new partition

Tags: mysql, linux

Changed mysql config (/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf) to point to new data directory & restarted.

Followed the procedure given on this link.

[https://linuxhint.com/change_mysql_data_directory_ubuntu/#:~:text=The%20default%20data%20directory%20for%20the%20MySQL%20database%20server%20is,%2Fetc%2Fmysql%2Fmysql](https://linuxhint.com/change_mysql_data_directory_ubuntu/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20data%20directory%20for%20the%20MySQL%20database%20server%20is,%2Fetc%2Fmysql%2Fmysql).

But in it he just copies data into new partition & never deletes source. So just wanted to confirm whether we are safe to delete the  default data directory or not.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok yes but there are a few things I would check first.

**Log in to mysql and check the data directory is correct**

```
$ mysql -u root -p
mysql> select @@datadir;
```

You should see a result showing your new data directory

**Create a new database and check that its added to new directory**

Obvious but if you create a new database, it should be stored under the new data directory. It's worth checking that it is.

**Leave the data directory alone for a while**

You could leave the old data directory alone for a few days while the database runs. Then check back and make sure nothing there has changed - the ibdata and iblogfile files haven't changed in the meantime.

Maybe over cautious but also may not be.